# Nested attributes and params.require error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-form-for

I am new to ruby on rails espacially nestes forms. I am trying to create an author and a book in the same form knowing that there's a many to many relationshio between them my code is presented below.
book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :exemplaires
has_many :talks, inverse_of: :book
has_many :subjects, through: :writings
has_many :writings
has_many :authors, through: :talks
accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors
validates :title, presence: true

end
```

author.rb:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :talks
 has_many :books, through: :talks
end
```

talk.rb

```
class Talk < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :book
 belongs_to :author
end
```

book_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  def index

 end
 def list
   @books= Book.all
 end
 def new
   @book = Book.new
   @author=@book.authors.new
 end
 def create
    @book= Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
     flash[:notice]='goood'
     redirect_to admin_manage_path
    else
     flash[:alert]='ouups'
     redirect_to root_url
    end
  end



  private

  def book_params
   params.require(:book).permit(:title, :pages, :resume, :authors_attributes)
  end
  end
```

books\new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add new book</h1>
  <%= form_for(@book) do |form| %>
     <%= form.label :title %>
     <%= form.text_field :title %>
     <%= form.fields_for :authors do |tag_form| %>

       <%= tag_form.label :f_name %>
       <%= tag_form.text_field :f_name %>
    <% end %>

   <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

what i got as error

> Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qpGng8tOiC/B5VX2tphuhAe+Wq1vx7it1vEO6XmwZmI=", "book"=>{"title"=>"booooooooooooook", "authors_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"f_name"=>"auuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuthor"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
>   Unpermitted parameters: authors_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to whitelist the `authors_attributes` fields too:

```
  def book_params
   params.require(:book).permit(:title, :pages, :resume, authors_attributes: [:f_name])
  end
```

Comment: thanks for responding but i already tried that and it gives me this error "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

Comment: This issue might be related to something else, but you are one step ahead now, because you definitely need to whitelist the author fields as I indicated. Can you post the full error you are getting ?

Comment: this is what render the server "
Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qpGng8tOiC/B5VX2tphuhAe+Wq1vx7it1vEO6XmwZmI=", "book"=>{"title"=>"kjqfghkjdgf", "authors_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"f_name"=>"fdqkhvfjkvkjv"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):
  app/controllers/books_controller.rb:29:in `[]'
  app/controllers/books_controller.rb:29:in `book_params'
  app/controllers/books_controller.rb:14:in `create'"